# How can I install an extension of a package in conda?

Tags: python, package, anaconda, conda

I am on my working Computer, so I do not have the admin rights to install things, which make package Installation quite tricky. I am using Anaconda prompt/ Conda for installing my packages: de_core_news_sm or any other German Extension as I will work in German language

I already successfully ran in my own environment and conda prompt:

```
activate MyEnv
pip install spacy
```

Now I am searching for a command similar to:

```
python -m spacy download de_core_news_sm
```

But if I run this, I get an error:

> Python: cannot open file 'spacy': no file or such dictionary

I also tried directly from conda with:

```
conda install -c conda-forge spacy-model-de_core_news_sm
```

which throws an error that I cannot use Python 3.6 for it, but I assume the newest Spacy is available for Python 3.6 or not?

My personalized environment was set up in the .condarc with the following scheme:
https://support.anaconda.com/customer/en/portal/articles/2921276-using-anaconda-behind-a-firewall-or-proxy

Answer (score 1):

You can try installing spacy in your Conda env through

```
conda install -c spacy spacy
```

and then try

```
python -m spacy download de_core_news_sm
```

Comment: when I do the second part with `python -m spacy download...` I get an error with HTTP Connection pool host...failed to etablish a new connection

Comment: @PV8 in this case set the proxy first in terminal eg `set HTTP_PROXY = <ur proxy >` and then run this command

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? Are you able to download the last release directly from https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/tag/de_core_news_sm-2.1.0? If you can, you can download from the site and just install it through pip install `/path/to/file/de_core_news_sm-2.1.0`

Comment: this is exactly the Problem, I am not able to download the file and i am behind a proxy

Comment: In this case, try as @prashantrana said in his previous comment, and then retry downloading it

Comment: but the enviorment is already set up for my own Proxy, this is why i set up the enviorment, do i Need to refere to it again?

Comment: if I would have the Option to download a file locally it would be all good, but all the Downloads are forbidden...

Comment: This is gonna be a difficult problem to solve, if your proxy is blocking download i don't think that you're going to be able to download that file in any way. A thing that you can do is just download the file under another connection, but i bet you already thought about it.

Comment: yes, so probably the best solution is to go with an admin password

Answer (score 0):

you need to call the spacy module using `-m` with this   python command

```
python -m spacy download de_core_news_sm
```

Comment: see comment above